# How to recreate a httpd.conf file deleted by mistake on LAMP?

Tags: lamp, httpd.conf

I on my ubuntu i'm trying to migrate from a wamp server (on windows) to a lamp server .
Unfortunatly i deleted the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file after the instalation... 
How to recreate this file (the original version) ?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Get the file from the LAMP installation files

2/ Use your best text editor

3/ Copy and modify your Wamp config.

This is 3 possible solutions, not steps ;)

Comment: 1/ how i do so ? i just did apt-get never moved in any folder or anything else, i'm sorry i'm not so familliar with linux, i'm practicing :)
2/ And rewrite everything?
3/ Copy and modify your Wamp config. this is what i tried but i stoped when i saw this LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/php5apache2_2.dll" do not know so much what to do...

Comment: If you did nothing worthy you should try reinstalling as mentioned by @Joachim

Comment: is there a way to reinstall just apache2? not the whole lamp pack?

Comment: The link given by Joachim will do that, remove Apache2 package and install new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you with the original version mean the one installed when Apache is first installed, the only way I know to work *(if you can't just do it the easy way and get the original file from another ubuntu machine)* is to [purge and reinstall Apache](http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/02/how-to-completely-reset-an-apache-instance-in-ubuntu/).

Be sure to - when giving the purge command, pay attention to any packages depending on Apache that may also need to be reinstalled after doing this.

Edit: You can probably extract the file from the Apache package, but I'm not at an Ubuntu machine so I can test and give you the commands to do that. I'm sure someone else here knows how to do it.

Comment: Hum i  follow thoose steps and something strange happen... i effectivly removed apache2 ( the folder was empty. ) then i reinstalled id and... httpd.conf is still empty ( sudo nano httpd.conf  :/ ) I'm sure before it was full!
+ apache2 -t gives me an error (bad use rname i guess it s defined in httpd.conf)...

Comment: @florent I just tested with a scratch install of Ubuntu 11.10, the default httpd.conf is indeed empty with all configuration in mods-enabled, sites-enabled and conf.d. In other words, whatever was in your httpd.conf was probably not there by default.

Comment: Yes i think too, anyway i resigned and install xampp wich i found simpler for me...